# Kivy app stops updating after going to the settings menu

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following Python code that builds a Kivy app. The app consists of a button and a label. The button that opens the setings menu. The text label is showing the current time. The label time is updated in the function on_start that uses the   Clock.schedule_interval to run the timer_loop function.
When I run the app the time text updates correctly every second as expected.
But as soon as go to the setings menu and then go back to the main menu the text label stops updating. It stays on the time the settings menu was opened.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: "Config"
        on_press: app.open_settings()
        background_color: (50/255, 255/255, 25/255, 1)
    Label:
        text: app.time
        color: (0, 1, 0, 1)
"""


class MyApp(App):
    time = StringProperty()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def timer_loop(self, *args):
        now = datetime.now()
        self.time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.timer_loop, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I tried using different variation of the on_pause and on_resume functions but it didnt fix the problem. I also confirmed the time_loop callback is still running correctly after going to the settings by adding a print statement.

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that I am going to use.

I switched to using MDApp and MDLabel from KivyMD instead of using the Kivy classes.

working code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: "Config"
        on_press: app.open_settings()
        background_color: (50/255, 255/255, 25/255, 1)
    MDLabel:
        text: app.time
        color: (0, 1, 0, 1)
"""


class MyApp(MDApp):
    time = StringProperty()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def timer_loop(self, *args):
        now = datetime.now()
        self.time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.timer_loop, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Whatever is causing the issue in Kivy seems to be fixed in KivyMD and since at some point I was going to probably switch to using KivyMD anyway I will do the switch now instead.

Comment: I think you should report the original issue as a bug to the kivy developers.